# Mobile version displaying all wrong after custom theme rewrites

Tags: customization, mobile

Apologies if this is a dumb question. I'm a total novice at this and still learning as I go.

I've been converting my site design into a WordPress custom theme using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h7gOJbIpmo&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) tutorial. So far everything's working great and displaying as intended on desktop, but the mobile version of the site is completely FUBARed. I believe the error(s) must be occurring somewhere in front-page.php because when I go in and copy/paste over the code with my original HTML, the mobile version of the site is restored.

Here's the code for front-page.php:

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<!-- Main Section -->

<main>
    <section id="main-content">
       <div class="main-content-container">
         <div class="title-container">
         <div id="title"><h1 class="site-title">Stage Fright Festival</h1>
         </div>
           </div>
         <div class="main-content-box">
           <div class="main-content-text">
           <h2 class="tagline">Queer. Horror. Theatre.</h2>
           <h3 class="coming-soon">Coming soon</h3>
           <div class="creepy-preview">
            <img src="./wp-content/themes/caitlin-nolan-custom-theme/assets/images/image-1.png" alt="Image 1" width="200">
            <img src="./wp-content/themes/caitlin-nolan-custom-theme/assets/images/image-2.jpg" alt="Image 2" width="200">
            <img src="./wp-content/themes/caitlin-nolan-custom-theme/assets/images/image-3.jpg" alt="Image 3" width="200">
            <img src="./wp-content/themes/caitlin-nolan-custom-theme/assets/images/image-4.jpg" alt="Image 4" width="200">
            <img src="./wp-content/themes/caitlin-nolan-custom-theme/assets/images/image-5.jpg" alt="Image 5" width="200">
          </div>
             <div class="mobile-links">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/StageFrightFestival"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/stagefrightfestival/"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a> 
                <a href="mailto:creeps@stagefrightfestival.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></i>
                  </a>
             </div>
             <div class="arrow">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-down-long"></i>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <?php
        if( have_posts() ){
            while( have_posts() ){
                the_post();
                the_content();
            }
        }
        ?>
        
         <div class="mission-statement-box">
            <div class="mission-statement-text">
                <h3 class="why-horror">
                  <img src="./wp-content/themes/caitlin-nolan-custom-theme/assets/images/stagefrightskull.png" alt="Left Skull">
                  Why horror?
                  <img src="./wp-content/themes/caitlin-nolan-custom-theme/assets/images/stagefrightskull.png" alt="Right Skull"></h3>
                <p class="queer-horror">Horror has long had a special connection to queer culture. In the late 18th and early 19th centuries, many male writers of the Gothic novels popular at the time were homosexuals, and used their stories to express forbidden and even unnamable desires. The monster or antagonist of a horror story can represent being “other” in the status quo world. Many horror storytellers—out or otherwise—have used the genre to express their own queerness, and to illustrate the fear of going against what society thought was permissible. For several decades in the 20th century, the Motion Picture Production Code made portraying gay relationships and themes illegal. Horror filmmakers would often code their stories so that queers could recognize themselves within, but the rest of the audience could choose to ignore the flags. Today, we may more openly tell LGBTQ+ stories, but the horror genre still appeals to people who feel like outsiders, iconoclasts, trailblazers, and boundary pushers.</p>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mailing-list-box">
                <h3 class="join-us">
                  <a href="http://eepurl.com/ic4pjv">Join our mailing list</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </section>
 </main>
 
 <?php
 get_footer();
 ?>
```

You can also view the live site [here](https://stagefrightfestival.com).

Any input you can offer is welcome. I have until the 29th to get this thing finished and I'm feeling the pressure.

Comment: The errors aren't with the .php, this is down to CSS. I checked the link and the mobile version looks pretty normal, it's the desktop where I see overlaps, etc. I think you just have to keep parsing through your CSS and making adjustments using `@media` queries in your stylesheets.